# Custom service dependency injection when testing a specific service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, dependency-injection

When testing services, is there a way to override the injected service as a dependency for a particular service, and not for all services at resolution time?

I'm trying to inject a mock service (`MockChild`) into another service (`Parent`) as a dependency, and have the mock service depend on the original service (`Child`). Something like:

```
Parent >> MockChild >> Child
```

The mocked service will be used in multiple locations, so I want to break it out of the `Parent` service and place it in its own file.

The issue that I am running into is that I can't inject the `MockChild` service into the `Parent` service, via:

```
var $rootScope, MockChild, Parent;

beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _MockChild_, _Parent_) {
  $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  MockChild = _Child_;
  Parent = _Parent_;
}));
```

and then later on use `$provide` to indicate that dependency injection should use `MockChild` when resolving `Child`, via:

```
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
  $provide.value('Child', MockChild);
}));
```

I can understand that this is most likely due to the injection rules being finalised at an application-wide level when `inject(...)` is called but for me the issue is that I need to have access to `Child` inside `MockChild`.

It seems to me that a local override is achieved when testing controllers by using the `$controller` service, providing explicit override arguments for the services that you need to inject. An example using the fictional `$service` service would look like this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($service, MockChild) {
  Parent = $service('Parent', {
    Child: MockChild
  });
});
```

My `MockChild` service definition looks like so:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('MockChild', ['$q', 'Child', function($q, Child) {
    var _children = [ 
      new Child(),
      new Child(),
      new Child()
    ];  

    return {
      all: function() {
        return $q(function(success, error) {
          if(success) {
            success(_children);
          }   
        }); 
      }   
    };  
  }]);
```

and my `Parent` service looks like so:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('Parent', ['$q', 'Child', function($q, Child) {
      var Parent = Parse.Object.extend('Parent');

      Parent.all = function() {
        return $q(function(success, error) {
          var results = cache.get('parents.all');
          if(results) {
            if(success) {
              success(results);
            }   
          } else {
            var result = new Parent();
            result.id = 'parent_id';
            result.getChildren().then(function() {
              success([result]);
            }); 
          }   
        }); 
      };  

      Parent.prototype.getChildren = function() {
        var meeting = this;
        return $q(function(success, error) {
          Child.all().then(function(children) {
            if(success) {
              success(children);
            }   
          }); 
        }); 
      };  

      return Parent;
    }]);
```

Comment: It sounds to me like you have a bit of problem with your overall testing approach. When unit testing X, you really shouldn't need to care about Y. You would just want to mock Y so that it return what X expects and focus solely on X. Alternatively, when testing integration, you'll want to avoid mocking X or Y so that you have that extra layer of certainty that they do in fact work together and that your mocks were accurate. I don't see any way that a sort of mixture of these two would be helpful.

Comment: I can understand that, and I could massage this to generate anonymous objects instead of creating new children via `new Child()`, but the overall question still remains; even if I don't have a dependency on `Child` from `MockChild` how can I inject `MockChild` into my test and then set that as the service to use whenever dependency injection tries to resolve `Child`?